# Custom domain for Github pages with Godaddy (.FR) is not working,

Tags: dns, github-pages

So I bought a domain which is souterrains-bapaume.fr and I am trying to link it to my Github pages website.

This is all my records:

[Godaddy records here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxfGl.png)

I set the custom domain on Github pages as well and I keep getting the same page:

This site can’t be reachedwww.souterrains-bapaume.fr’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I have another website with another domain with an extension of .me and all work perfectly with the exact same records so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your domain was not properly configured or not successfully registered.
The .fr root zone can not found your dns. You can use **dig** and **whois** command to check.

Dig result:

**souterrains-bapaume.fr**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKpNC.png)

**google.fr**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoqHs.png)

Comment: Please do not include images of text. Include the text itself in the answer (wrapped in `\`\`\`` or indented four spaces).